# Contenteditable inline element becomes a block when multiple rows of text are present in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm having a layout problem in IE (11) that I don't run into in Chrome (32.0) or Firefox (26.0), and I'm hoping someone can help me out with a work-around.

I have a large field of text that is to be user editable, using `contentEditable="true"`, and has an image `float`-ing within it. In FF and Chrome this works just fine, and the text flows around the float as expected. In IE however, if I have an inline element (a `span`, or something like a `div` with `display:inline`), it acts like a block element, taking the full width of its container, and popping everything down below the floating element.

After some testing, the generalized case seems to be that as soon as an editable inline element in IE has more than one row of text, it starts acting as a block element.

Demonstration code:

```
<div style="height:100px;width:100px;float:right;background-color:red;"></div>
<span contenteditable="true">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</span>
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Edit: Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DashielN/WwPep/), so it's easier to poke at.

Comment: did you try put float: left on span?

Comment: Yup. That just makes it broken in all three browsers.

Comment: I'd advise against contenteditable. Use textarea instead.

Comment: That would obviously defeat the point in this case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `<span>` to `<p>`.

Comment: i believe he doesn't expect to see element showing under image ... the use of overflow should as well help him to wonder about floatting and non floatting behavior, so next times he knows he has to prevent some side effect unexpected by beginner :)

Comment: I think we're interpetting his needs differently. Regardless, the answer is rarely found in wrapping more and more tags around content.

Comment: Having the element's background (if there is one) show up behind the image is fine in this case, so this solution works for me. Also works with a straight `div` instead of the `span`.

Comment: That being said, I really don't get why a span and/or its contents wouldn't flow around the floater when block elements make special accommodations to do so. Works fine that way for everyone else, but I guess IE is still a special snowflake some times. :p Thanks!

Comment: Since content editable can hold any tags , it should not be an inline tag on first place :) http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cCEyk As long you fixed your problem ..

Comment: I guess that makes enough sense that I can see why they'd do it that way... although in that case it should really work just like a `div` or `p` and float the element within the block, I'd think.

Answer (score 0):

treat the layout like you would for any other tag following a floatting element. :)

You may wrap the `span` in `div` (or any block element that suits the structure) with `overflow:hidden;` or set

```
span { 
display:block;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

see for instance  http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ as a reminder